# invalid_grant on OAuth2 request when obtaining access_token from SSO in App

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I have an iOS App with an Uber API integration where I use SSO to authenticate the user and then save the accessToken & refreshToken locally on my device. Then I'm calling my server who uses a javascript background function to call the node-uber (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uber) library to make a request to Uber.
So far, I'm trying to set up the uber client with my 2 local tokens from the SSO login like this:

```
var uber = new uberClient({
    client_id: '...',
    client_secret: '...',
    server_token: '...',
    name: 'My App',
    sandbox: true, //optional
    access_token: accessToken,
    refresh_token: refreshToken
  });
```

afterwards I want to call the uber.requests.getEstimatesAsync endpoint like this:

```
uber.requests.getEstimatesAsync({
      "start_latitude": pickupLocation["lat"],
      "start_longitude": pickupLocation["lng"],
      "end_latitude": dropoffLocation["lat"],
      "end_longitude": dropoffLocation["lng"]
      })
      .then(function(res) { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); 
      })
      .error(function(err) { 
        console.error(err); 
      });
})
```

Though every time I get an "invalid_grant" error 400 while doing this. Did I make a mistake authenticating myself or setting up the Uber client wrong? Is it even possible to use my SSO accessToken & refreshToken then on the uber client, which does a OAuth2 authentification? I thought that both access and refresh token should probably be the same what Uber sends back to be for SSO & OAuth2.
I'm using a Developer account for doing this, therefore I should actually have all the required permissions for the request endpoint, but I also obtained them previously in the App correctly.

This thread on the official uber documentation explains potential reasons but I guess they don't really apply to my case, do they? https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#common-problems-and-solutions

Any security expert here who can help?
Best regards,
Matt

P.S.: I also posted this question on the Uber library I'm using for making those requests, but nobody seems to be able to help me there so far. https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber/issues/70

Edit: The following picture shows my authentication setup so far:

[image]

Comment: You have a problem with authentication. Can you please post your authentication flow - and explain in details how you implemented SSO in your application.

Comment: Can you please confirm do you still have a problem with your implementation - I have checked our logs for your app id: gSnfYTzSL****** and looks like you are making the successful request to all Uber endpoints.

Comment: Hey Sasa, thanks for the reply. Yes the problem still exists. You probably saw my SSO activity in the logs which works out fine! Though the above mentioned problem is with my database / firebase background function and it still doesn't work. The function on the server basically can't execute the function and gets an invalid_grant error when trying to make a request on the users behalf. I added a drawing for the authentication flow above.

Comment: Your SSO flow looks ok - and you are getting valid access_token and refresh_token. Not sure what is your Firebase background function doing - if you are trying to get an estimate and get invalid grant error - we can not see it in our logs so looks like it is not associated with your client_id. Make sure you re passing correct parameter values. Like I say you are making successful estimates and ride requests calls - so it looks like you have two different implementations? If you still have problems let me know - I will contact you on your email.

Comment: Hey Sasa, I made it work last weekend. It looks like if it was a problem with then node-uber library. I made a separate http request without the library and was able to get it. It also works woth with SSO and OAuth2 which is awesome. Thanks for your help though. I'll provide a solution later here if somebody else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I think was a problem with the library itself. Because once I made the request with http with the "request" library (https://github.com/request/request) it worked. Include for that at the top of your code:

```
var request = require('request');
```

Both OAuth2 and SSO accessToken worked. You should give the method a pickupLocation with latitude and longitude and your obtained accessToken from Uber like this:

```
function getAllAvailableUberProducts(pickupLocation, accessToken){
    var lat = pickupLocation["lat"].toString();
    var lng = pickupLocation["lng"].toString();

    var options = {
        uri: "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lng,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
            "Accept-Language": "en_US",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(body).products);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps someone.